# Finding security vulnerabilites in my code - LDAP Search

Tags: java, performance, security, ldap

How do i find vulnerabilites in my code here. My assignment is asking me to find the vulnerabilites using no programm so no spotbugs, etc. Is there any website and/or tips for me to find the vulnerabilites. Here's my code

I've tried to google but i've had a hard time finding solid website or doc for finding or helping me find vulnerabilites.

User search in an LDAP directory:

```
public class LsiLDAPUsers
{
    private void searchRecord( String userSN, String userPassword ) throws NamingException
    {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

        try
        {
            DirContext dctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

            SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
            String[] attributeFilter = { "cn", "mail" };
            sc.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
            sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            String base = "dc=lsi,dc=com";

            String filter = "(&(sn=" + userSN + ")(userPassword=" + userPassword + "))";

            NamingEnumeration<?> results = dctx.search(base, filter, sc);
            while (results.hasMore())
            {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) results.next();
                Attributes attrs = (Attributes) sr.getAttributes();
                Attribute attr = (Attribute) attrs.get("cn");
                System.out.println(attr);
                attr = (Attribute) attrs.get("mail");
                System.out.println(attr);
            }
            dctx.close();
        }
        catch (NamingException e)
        {
            // Forward to handler
        }
    }
}
```

I need to make the code more secure basically. This is one of my code. But i have a lot of work on other part of it. I just need to get a good exemple and/or tips from this one, thanks !!

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP?

Comment: I believe this exercise is more around testing your ability to understand secure coding than LDAP or performance. Good luck!

Comment: You should supply the filter and the filter arguments separately, rather than building a single filter string, and you should separate the action of searching for the user by `sn` from a subsequent action of attempting to bind as that user, via `Context.reconnect()`. See the Javadoc. Also `sn` is just the surname: it is a poor choice of attribute for searching. Use something unique, such as `mail` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few hints:

- a major pillar of secure coding is proper verification of *user input*. That is the main entry point for most hacks.
- using SSL or TLS for network connections is today's default
- anonymous searching is disabled in most systems today